# Post build unit testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, post-build-event

I would like to run unit tests in the post build event for Visual Studio 2012 using MVC default testing.

Is there a configuration setting or what is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Most unit testing frameworks support a command line mode. Presuming you get the binaries in the project, you could probably pretty easily wire that up.

That said, you are probably looking for [this product](http://ox.no/software/continuoustesting).

Comment: According the documentation for this product it does not support Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Good point -- I clicked through to their twitter and it made sense why they didn't support 2012. Continuious Testing is built in -- see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/06/18/visual-studio-2012-rc-what-s-new-in-unit-testing.aspx

Comment: Yep, 'run tests after build' is built into Visual Studio Ultimate which I do not have --- I think I am looking for something on the post-build event command line like the following (which is for testing with Nunit in VS2010.
$(SolutionDir)\packages\Nunit.2.5.9.10348\tools\nunit-console $(TargetPath)

Comment: That should work, but I wouldn't want it wired in as such. When the tests fail, the post build step fails so your build fails which means VS won't fire up the debugger. You might want to look into a CI server to enforce this sort of tests must pass thing.